# Responsive image scaling on resize

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I am making a website that should be responsive on mobile phones and I need to make a circle shaped with icons in it. I made the circle shape an image and the icons too. But when resizing the window the icons do not keep their ratio like the circle image. I am using HTML5 and CSS3.

```css
.theCircle {
  position: relative;
}
#img1 {
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
}
#img2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  left: 4%;
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="theCircle">
  <img id="img1" src="circle.png">
  <img id="img2" src="pin.png">
</div>
```

Here's my code showing the divs and styling. This is a picture showing how the circle is scaling up when the window is bigger but the icon isn't.

Any ideas please?

[image]

Comment: The pointer icon top & left percentage is always respective to window size; not image size/position. You need to write some scripts/css trics to find the position respective to image size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using images make this with pure html and css

```css
*{
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
.theCircle{
  width:50vw;
  height:50vw;
  border:2px solid black;
  margin:auto;
  border-radius:25vw;
  position:relative;
}
.innerCircle{
  width:40vw;
  height:40vw;
  border:2px solid black;
  margin:auto;
  border-radius:25vw;
  position:absolute;
  top:5vw;
  left:5vw;
}
#img2{
  position:absolute;
  top:22vw;
  left:0;
  width:5vw;
  height:5vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="theCircle">
  <div class="innerCircle">  
  </div>
  <img id="img2" src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ui-5/502/marker-512.png" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can completely rely on CSS3 (which is only the case if you don't support older browsers) you should be able to fix this using vh and vw.

For example: If you set both width and height of a item to 50vw it will always be half as wide as the viewport and exactly same height (always square).

Can't write a complete example without your png-files and you should check the browser-support for vw and vh (for example you need IE9+).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, using vh and vw seem to work to some extent. Is there a good way in practice to "rig" the icon to the circle? for example I need to place four icons inside the border of the circle and I need everything to scale together in order to maintain ratio so icons do not get out of their intended place.

Comment: I don't think it is possible besides position the items with position ??vh/??vw which isn't very comfortable at all. As you use a circle maybe doing it with svg is more handy. It isn't as complicated as you might think and it can be maniuplated real easy using a few lines of JS-Code in case you need it dynamic. But using SVG leads to checking the browser support for it again! SVG is not supported by all browsers (especially IE)